# center map if id @clicked in the looped

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a two components. first one is for the articles content that I am looping. And second one is google map for the articles addresses... They are connected in store.js. No problem with that. And I am trying to center the map to if any articles's id clicked in component one. But having some problems about how to implement clicked event to google map component's listener?

What I thought, using event bus for the situation. And send which "id" clicked.

### UPDATED

**articles component**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr :key="item.id" v-for="item in articles" @clicked="changeCenter(item.id)">
            <th>
                <img :src="item.image" alt="">
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>{{item.name}}</p>
                <p>{{item.address.substr(0,40)}}...</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id:item.id} }"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></router-link>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And add the method.

```
methods: {
    changeCenter(id){
        eventBus.$emit("centerMap", id);
    },
},
```

and on the other side **google map component** is below.

in `created()` hook I am catching the id that clicked. But I **can't** access the value inside the `buildMarkers()` function. I mean I can `console.log(this.centerid)` in `created()` hook there is no problem. I can see the data that I am passing. But when the time come to put the `this.centerid` in the `buildMarkers()` or any other methods, `centerid` is start to being undefined

```
created(){
    eventBus.$on("centerMap", (id) => {
        this.centerid = id;
    })
},
```

and rest is a a bit mistery to me. google map code is right below.

```
data(){
    return {
        markers:[],
        infoWindows: [],
        centerid: "",
    };
},
mounted(){
    this.initMap();
    this.clearMarkers();
    this.buildMarkers();
},
created(){
    eventBus.$on("centerMap", (id) => {
        this.centerid = id;
    })
},
watch: {
    articles(){
        this.clearMarkers();
        this.buildMarkers();
    }
},
methods: {
    initMap(){

        const japan = {
            lat: 35.652832,
            lng: 139.839478
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 7,
            // maxZoom: 10,
            center: {lat: japan.lat, lng: japan.lng}
        })
    },
    buildMarkers(){
        var map = this.map;
        this.markers = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < this.articles.length; i++){

          // some codes...
          // some codes...

            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 0
                },
                position: position,
                map: this.map,
                labelClass: "markerClass",
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 30),
                labelContent: label,
            });

            this.markers.push(marker);

            if (this.articles[i].id === this.centerid) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                    map.setZoom(10);
                });
            }
        }
    },
    clearMarkers(){
        for( var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++ ){
            this.markers[i].setMap( null );
        }
    },
},
```

The problem is at this part. I am not sure how to handle this. Like I said before. I can't access the `centerid`to 's value.

```
if (this.articles[i].id === this.centerid) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, function () {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(10);
  });
}
```

Comment: "I can't access the centerid value." Why not? What's the problem you're running into? Is it set correctly but you can't access it or is it not set at all?
Also since you're already using the global state store there isn't really a reason to introduce an eventbus on top of that for your usecase. Just use a `centeredArticle` in the store.

Comment: I can `console.log(this.centerid)` in `created()` hook there is no problem. I can see the data that I am passing. But when the time come to put the `this.centerid` in the buildMarkers() or any other methods, `centerid` is start to being undefined?? @TommyF

Comment: Have you checked if there is an additional event on your bus that resets it to `undefined`? Can you log it inside of your `buildMarkers`?

Comment: yes I can log my `buildMarkers()` no problem with that part. for example, I can log `this.centerid` inside created() hook too... I can send the ID everytime I click in the loop component. But the problem starts when I pass the `centerid` inside `buildMarkers` it starts being undefined. Because of that I don't know my center listener works or not... @TommyF

Comment: See if you can set up a minimal example highlighting the problem on codesandbox. Then it is much easier to help.